# SSL + Jquery + Ajax

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, security, ssl

I starting too look at a bit of security into my site. My site I would consider a very low security risk as it has really no personal information from the user other than email.

However the security risk will go up a bit as I am partnering with a company and the initial password for this companies users will be the same password they use essentially to get onto the network and every piece of software.

So I have up my security( what is fine by me...I wanted to get around to this anyways).

So one of my security concerns is this.

1. A user logs in.
2. form submit(non ajax is done).
3. Password is hashed & Salted and compared to one in the database.
4. Reject or let them proceed.

So this uses no jquery or ajax but is just asp.net mvc and C#. Still if my understanding is right the password is sent in clear text.

So if a use SSL and I would not need to worry about that is this correct?

If that is true is that all I need?

Second the user can change their password at anytime. This is done through ajax. So when the password is sent it is sent in clear text( and I can verify this by looking at firebug).

So if I have SSL enabled on this page is that all I need or do I need to do more?

So I am just kinda confused of what I need to make the password being sent to the server(both ajax and full post ways secure).

I am not sure if I need to do more then SSL or if that is enough and if it is not enough what is the next layer of security?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use HTTPS/SSL for your page, your AJAX requests will (by default) be handled the same way, so yes this would eliminate all the clear-text issues and you'll get all the security benefits of SSL with your AJAX requests as well.

I would say for most sites this provides a sufficient level of protection, as much as is *sane* anyway.  Keep in mind that nothing is 100% secure (go to any mainstream conference, the security talks will scare you :), it may be 100% secure *so far*, but it rarely remains that way.  That being said, SSL is the most effective security mechanism/deterrent readily available, and it's the best route to go.

Also, SSL is the *cheapest* in terms of development time, you may not need to change not one line of code in your app to get it working, just make sure to keep your certificates valid/up-to-date.

Comment: Cool then I probably just implement HTTPS/SSL until a need of something more is needed. So for my ajax calls do I change them all to Https instead of Http? Should I make all calls https or only these ones that send the passwords? So what I am getting add is making everything a secure call give a hit on performance or slow down the calls that actual use it?

Answer (score 1):

if you are using SSL your data sent accross the server is well taken care by SSL let it be a ajax hit or simple hit